# How to get code to compile with PayRoll Datatype intemplate? Works with integers

Tags: c++

I can get the code to compile and work properly with integers, however when i try to use another data type it does not compile. Using templates

It appears to be an issue with the display function but no matter what i try it does not work.
 i have included the main file and the SUList file for reference. the integer block of code works and compiles and prints fine, but whwn implementing another datatype the program will not compile and work as it should.

it seems to be an issue with the display function that i also reference a payroll function with a printcheck function that works properly when seperatly tested.

```
'''`'''
// Implementation file for the SUList Class
#include "SUList.h"
#include "PayRoll.h"
#include "SUStack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;



template <class DataType>
DataType SUList<DataType>::display()
{
    int a;
   // PayRoll myList;

    int num = size();
    if (num == 0)
    {
        throw "List is empty...\n";
    }
    if(typeid(DataType) == typeid(a))
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=num; i++)
        {
            std::cout << head->data << std::endl;
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
    if(typeid(DataType) == typeid(PayRoll))
    {
        //myList.printCheck();
    }
}









Main.cpp

#include<iostream>
#include "SUList.h"
#include "SUStack.h"
#include "SUQueue.h"
#include "PayRoll.h"
#include "SUStack.cpp"
#include "SUList.cpp"
#include "SUQueue.cpp"

int main(){
  SUList<int> myList;
  SUList<PayRoll> pList;
  SUStackList<PayRoll> pStackList;

  /**
   * Test the SUList using ints
 */  

  myList.putFront(1);
  myList.putFront(6);
  myList.putFront(2);
  myList.putBack(4);
  myList.putBack(5);
  myList.putFront(3);

  myList.display();

  std::cout << "++++++++++++" << std::endl;

  /**
   * Test the SUList using PayRoll
   */

  pList.putFront(PayRoll("Bob", 20, 35));
  pList.putFront(PayRoll("Alice", 10, 35));
  pList.putBack(PayRoll("Charlie", 25, 35));
  pList.putBack(PayRoll("Diana", 10, 35));
  pList.putFront(PayRoll("Eve", 30, 35));

 // pList.display();


  return 0;`
```

Comment: *However when i try to use another data type it does not compile.*  -- What is the exact error?  Also using `typeid` when you're supposed to be using templates seems to me a huge design flaw.  You're defeating the whole purpose of templates by using `typeid`.

Comment: Your `display` function lies.  The declaration says it returns a `DataType` object, but there are no `return` statements inside the function.  I recommend either changing the return type to `void` or returning a `DataType` object.

Comment: You should not have `if` statement based on data type.  Instead, you should require that `operator<<` be defined for the `DataType`.  Otherwise, you'll have to keep changing your List template for each data type.  See `std::list`.

Comment: To add to my first comment, I am betting that your usage of`typeid` is what is causing the issue.  If the template argument is `std::string`, and you have code in your template function body that has any code assuming the type is `int`, then that will not compile.  Templates don't work that way -- it requires more sophistication (std::enable_if, template specialization) if you are trying to filter out or have different behavior based on template type.  Or do as Thomas Matthews suggests -- if the type doesn't compile, then it doesn't satisfy the requirements for your template.